# Design considerations behind `O` (a.k.a. BigOh, a.k.a. Landau Order)

Tags: syntax, series-expansion, implementation-details

This works without any warnings: `O[Log[x]]`.

This raises a warning: `O[x^2]`.

I have a few questions around this:

1. Why is it a good idea for `O[x^2]` to raise a warning when `O[Log[x]]` does not?
2. Is `O[Log[x]]` meaningfully useful in *Mathematica* given the semantics of its `O[]`?
3. How does one represent $\mathcal{O}(\log(x-x_o))$ naturally in *Mathematica*? (Probably there is no way because it is useless...)
4. Why is `O[x, x0]^2` the representation chosen by *Mathematica* authors instead of something like `O[(x-x0)^2]`?

Comment: The proper syntax is `O[x]^2`. As to why this is, that is likely something that only the authors can answer (it has been that way since version 1). For giggles, try `O[x]^2 // InputForm`.